# How to use Forms in React to edit item from another React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Simply, imagine a List page with "add/edit" modal (bootstrap) to manage items in the list.

The list itself is a react component:

```
<List Items={items} />
```

The List component renders array of list items which are react components too:

```
<ListItem Item={item} />
```

The "add/edit" form is also a react component as well:

```
<ItemForm Item={item} />
```

each item in the list will contain edit link that will trigger add/edit modal to show and populate the form with the values of selected item to edit.

**The question** is how can I pass `item object` to the form `<ItemForm />` for edit using the edit link in the `<ListItem />` that is nested inside  `<List />`

```js
class ListItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <label>{this.props.Item.Name}</label> - 
        <a> Edit </a>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

class List extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const rows = [];

    this.props.Items.forEach(item => {
      rows.push(<ListItem key={item.ItemID} Item={item} />);
    });

    return (
      <ul>
        {rows}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

var sampleItems = [
  {ItemID: 1, Name: 'item 1'},
  {ItemID: 2, Name: 'item 2'},
  {ItemID: 3, Name: 'item 3'}
]

ReactDOM.render(
  <List Items={sampleItems} />, 
  document.getElementById("list")
);

class ItemForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { Name: '' };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const name = target.name
    this.setState({
      [name]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //handles submit code
    alert(this.state.Name + ' saved!');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form key="item-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Item Name:</label>
          <input
            name="Name"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.Name}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <ItemForm />,
  document.getElementById("form-container")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="list"></div>
<hr/>
<div id="form-container"></div>
<hr/>
```

Comment: Where are you rendering modal?

Comment: You don't want to pass the item to the form, you want to set one of the items as active once an edit button is clicked, and then you want the form, when submitted, to call a function passed to the component in the props that updates the value.

Comment: @MikhailKatrin Modal is not included in the code snippet, but you can consider the form is rendered inside modal.

Comment: @chbchb55 how to set one item as active? active you mean: the item values are rendered inside the form?

Comment: You need to keep that in the state of the top level React Component.

Comment: @chbchb55 then I need a common parent for them, that one is not done.

Comment: Generally, in React, there is a top level component named `App` and is attached to the DOM node `<div id='app'></div>` and `App` is the only class rendered to DOM. Or if you want you could use **Redux** to keep the state outside of component at all